# Field + Content Type Management in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, content-type

I have one requirement

Content type : Items

Fields : Name, Category, Sub Category

[ Category(only one value allow from drop down)

Sub Category(value on base of selected category, multiple value allow while add item)]

[image]

Ex : Category : Fruit , Flower , Tree

[image]

Ex : Sub Category for Fruit : Banana
                         Apple
                         Orange

Ex : Sub Category for Flower : Rose
                          Sun Flower

[image]

How can I develope such kind of features?
whether is it require to create new content type for category and sub category?
I created content type for category and sub category.
but in sub category how can i add drop down menu to select only one category?
also in items content type how can use it?

I referred entity relation and conditional module but not getting perfect solution.

I am new in drupal.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a standard taxonomy and the [Hierarchical select module](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) may be what you need.

Comment: Using Hierarchical select module module and widget Hierarchical Select, but field conditional state module not work with it. How can I solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually think [Simple Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) is probably a better option because it allows similar interaction in Views as well.